# SLIME typeout frame does not show slime-autodoc messages

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

I cannot get `slime-autodoc-mode` messages to be displayed in the [slime-typeout-frame](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Typeout-frames.html). My goal is to have the argument list that normally appears in the echo buffer appear in this typeout frame so that I can have a history of it, and have it always showing. The only way I've been able to get messages into the typeout frame is to evaluate

```
(slime-typeout-message "Some formatted message here %d." 1234)
```

Is there something more I need to connect to get it to work? Is the typeout frame deprecated?

P.S. I'm not 100% attached to the typeout frame. I really really just want to be able to have a buffer for `slime-autodoc-mode` messages.

Emacs Version: 24.4.1

SBCL Version: 1.2.2

I installed SLIME via quicklisp-slime-helper.

`(slime-changelog-date)`: 2014-08-01

My Emacs config:

```
(progn
  ;; (ql:quickload :quicklisp-slime-helper)
  (load (expand-file-name "~/quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))
  ;; Replace "sbcl" with the path to your implementation
  (setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
  (setq slime-contribs '(slime-fancy slime-typeout-frame))

  (add-hook 'slime-mode-hook (lambda ()
                   (require 'slime-typeout-frame)
                   (slime-ensure-typeout-frame)
                   ))

  ;; Start slime when editing lisp.
  (add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook (lambda () (slime-mode t)))
  (add-hook 'inferior-lisp-mode-hook (lambda () (inferior-slime-mode t))))
```